# Retry options in Redis Stream to read values

Tags: java, redis, stream

I have created a Redis Stream with XADD using AsyncCommands. Redis StreamListener will listen the stream when values adds into the stream. In case listener fails to read stream due to connectivity issue with Redis or some other reasons, Is there any way we can retry with defined period.